# Check the following sets are algebraic or not?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-geometry

Affine n - spaces over a field $K$ is the cartesian product of the field $K$ with itself $n$ time and it is denoted by $\mathbb A^n(K)$.

$X$ is a subset of Afine n - spaces $\mathbb A^n(K)$ is called algebraic if there exist an ideal I of $K[x_1,X_2, \cdots , X_n]$ such that $V(I) = X$, where $V(I) =  \{f \in I : f(a_1, a_2 , \cdots, a_n) = 0  \ \ \text{for all} \  (a_1, \cdots , a_n) \in X \}$

> > Which of the following subsets are algebraic or not ?
> >
> > 1. $A = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb A^2(\mathbb R) : y = \sin x \}$
> > 2. $B=\{ (\cos t, \sin t) \in \mathbb A^2 (\mathbb R) : t \in \mathbb R \}$
> > 3. $C=\{ (z,w) \in \mathbb A^2(\mathbb C) : |z|^2  + |w|^2 = 1 \}$
> > 4. $D =\{ ( \cos t , \sin t, t) \in \mathbb A^3(\mathbb R) : t \in \mathbb R \}$

I have an idea  about (2), let $I = < x^2 + y^2 -1>$, then $B = I$, I think $(1), (3), (4)$ are not algebraic , but i do not know how to prove .

I would be thankful if someone help me to prove. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one, suppose a polynomial f(x,y) vanishes on the locus y=sin(x).  Then f(x,0) is a polynomial in one variable vanishing at each multiple of 2pi.  What does that tell us about f(x,0)?

Comment: Similar we can do for the 4th  part. and what c.an you say abut the forth part.